# How to handle output <function <lambda> at 0x0000021B33C63E20>

Tags: python, lambda

My code:

```
m1 = [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
m2 = [[0, 1, 0], [20, 0, -1], [-1, -2, 0]]
m3 = [[0, 1, 0], [20, 0, -1], [-1, -2, 0]]

a = lambda x, y: (x * y), m1, m2
print(*list(a))
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAIJX.png):

> <function  at 0x0000021B33C63E20> [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0,
> 0, 1]] [[0, 1, 0], [20, 0, -1], [-1, -2, 0]]
> How to remove from output  <function  at 0x0000021B33C63E20>?

Comment: `a` is a tuple containing a `lambda x, y: x*y`, the list `m1` and the list `m2`. If you don't want the lambda to be in the output, don't add it to the tuple, or print `a[1:]` which slices out the first element of the tuple

Comment: That's the first element of the tuple of three things in your variable (the other two are `m1` and `m2` which are apparently lists). Don't add it to the front of `a` if you don't want it there.

Comment: What did you expect that to do?  You have created a list containing a lambda function, and two of your three lists.  You never called the function.  I was going to suggest an alternative, but I don't know what you expect to multiply.

Comment: did you want to call `a()` perhaps passing in some parameters?

Comment: I need to output the multiplication of each element of a list by each element of another list. But at the same time, so that the original lists do not change. I know, for this you need to make a copy of the deepcopy.

Comment: Please provide an example of expected output, because it's not really clear what you want to multiply...

Comment: m1 and m2 are classes of matrices. I need to multiply matrices. That is, the first element of m1 to the first element of m2. So that m1 and m2 do not change as tuples

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, in Python, `x, y, z` is a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) containing the objects x, y and z as elements. In your case, you define `a` to be a tuple containing:

- A lambda function
- `m1`
- `m2`

You probably meant to assign the function to a variable, e.g. `func = lambda x, y: (x * y)`, and evaluate the function on some given parameters, e.g.

```
func = lambda x, y: (x * y)
print(*[func(x, y) for x, y in zip(range(4), range(4))])
# 0 1 4 9
print(*[func(x, y) for x, y in zip([2, 4, 6], [3, 5, 7])])
# 6 20 42
```